# C# declare class member variable type of itself pointer

Tags: c#

I write *linked list* for study with C#

but, why this code occur error.

```
class testClass{
    testClass* pointerValue;
}
```

Error code:

> Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a
>   managed type ('testClass')

i dont know why this error occur. help me

Comment: Why do you want an *unsafe pointer*? `class testClass { testClass pointerValue;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `testClass` has been declared as `class` (not as `struct`) it's a *reference type* and you have no need in any explicit *unsafe pointer*:

```
class testClass { 
  // reference to testClass instance or null
  testClass pointerValue; 
}
```

Comment: No _any pointer_, because this is a pointer - but a hidden pointer.

Comment: The error says, that he want to get the size. So the compiler want to know, how "big" the pointer should be ? like what adressroom he has to allocate ?

Comment: @Morta: _"... or declare a pointer to a managed type testClass"_

Comment: ou.... my major language is C++. something was ambigous. in c++ pointer type is always 4byte. but, you guys says 'C# must know about size that memory was directed by pointer' that right?

Comment: @naiad: `testClass` is a *managed* class (e.g. it can *collected* by Garbage Collector, it can be *moved* in the memory) that's why we can't address this kind of objects via *unsafe pointers* (which in fact are addresses only). But you can, say, put `unsafe {int i = 123; int* p = &i; ...}`